# Detect any focused textfield flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

Right now i have a list of textfield with FocusScope since i want the textfield take effect only when the text field is out of focus, below are the example of the textfield

```
                 FocusScope(
                  child: Focus(
                    focusNode: node,
                    onFocusChange: (focus) {
                      if (!focus) {
                        if (widget.controllers[3].text.isNotEmpty) {
                          widget.bloc.add(
                            // bloc function
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: TextField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(30),
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]')),
                      ],
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                      hintText: '',
                      title: '',
                      editingController: widget.controllers[3],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

At the bottom of the page, there will be button to continue to the next page, however after the clicking the button i want the app to unfocus every text field first before proceed with the button onclick funtion, how do i do it? Maybe something like a function where it can detect if there's any focus on a text field

```
                      FlatButton(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){
                            _unfocus(context, state);                             
                        }
                        child: Text(
                          'Continue',
                          style: medium(
                            16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```

unfocus funtion

```
void _unfocus(
  BuildContext context,
  State state,
) {
  FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
  if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
    currentFocus.unfocus();
  } else {
    // go to next page function ()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to `unfocus` in your `onPressed`

```
  void _unfocus() {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: i already added the function, you may refer the edited question, but why do i always get it go to the first if statement only, with or without focusing on text field?